# filter and sort for multiple tables in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have multiple tables in the same page like

Table 1 (contain hotel name,price,stars)

Table 2 (contain hotel name,price,stars)

Table 1 (contain hotel name,price,stars)

Table 3 (contain hotel name,price,stars)

Table 4 (contain hotel name,price,stars)

..... and so on as envelopes.

I need JQUERY PLUGIN to filter and sort the data in tables like price sorter from low to high price and filter for hotel name. Can I find this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Would jQuery [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) work for you?

Or any of the gazillions table sorting/filtering that can be found out there:

- http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/05/jquery-filter-sort-plugins.html
- http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/30-amazing-jquery-tables/
- ...

Comment: My Idea said which I have some tables in the same page I need jquery plugin which work to sort all tables depends on hotel name which consider as row in each table and price the same thing just one click make sort for all tables according to the sorting criteria.Is there any plugin work to make sorting and filtering for inline values like above values.

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle so that people can have a look at your code.